# Constructing Borders Around Adjacent Elements

Tags: html, css, border

Is it possible to have a continuous border around adjacent html elements that have different heights?

I have tried overlapping the elements by the border width and setting the left border of the second element to white, but this creates a black/white bevel on the corner (http://jsfiddle.net/h4FwJ/). I would like to achieve the same look as in that fiddle, but without the bevelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the div1 style to this

```
border-left-width:0px;    
margin-left: -10px;  
background-color:White;
```

Comment: I think you mean: border-left-width:0px;    
margin-left: -10px;  
background-color:White;   http://jsfiddle.net/pseqp/

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the fiddle was only lining up for me with -14px before.

Comment: This is fairly close, but also requires `padding-left:10px;` to keep the the `div` contents in the same place. Thanks!